# How to give the choice to open a new window or stay on the same on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where I submit it on button click. I want to give the user the choice to submit them for on the same window or open a new one. For example, if the user wants to submit on the same window, he/she can left click on the button, and if the user wants to open a new window, they can right-click and then choose open in a new window. Is it possible to Implement this method?

For now, I have a form, if I set the target to "_self", it will remain on the same page and "_blank" with redirect you to a different page.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('Request-Compound.run_script') }}" target="_self">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btns" value="{{button.value}}" name="new_btn" onclick="{{button.onclick}}"/>
</form>
```

The expected result is to be able to give the user the choice to submit the form on the same window or on a new tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't submit a form when the user right-clicks and chooses "Open in new window."

You might implement a drop-down button where the main part submits to the current window but there's a part that's a drop-down arrow offering the choice to submit to a new window (like [this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/#nesting) from Bootstrap).

The "submit to new window" would update `target` before submitting, obviously.

Here's a **really** crude example (on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/t3quoxzy/) — Stack Snippets don't allow forms in any way or shape):

```
<form action="https://google.com/search">
    <div>
        <label>Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="kittens"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="button-menu">
            <input type="submit" class="current-window" value="Submit">
            <span class="menu-toggler">V</span>
            <div class="button-menu-content">
                <input type="submit" class="new-window" value="Submit to New Window">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".button-menu .menu-toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".button-menu").toggleClass("menu-open");
});
$(".new-window").on("click", function() {
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    form.prop("target", "_blank");
});
$(".current-window").on("click", function() {
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    form.prop("target", "_self");
});
```

Obviously, again, that's very crude, your UI toolkit (whether homebrew or one of the standard ones) will let you make it look a lot smarter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do sth like this:

```
$('button [type="submit"]').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // show a popover with your "open in new window button"
});

openInNewWindowButton.on('click', function() {
   $('form').attr('target', '_blank').submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The 'target' attribute specifies a name or a keyword that indicates where to display the response that is received after submitting the form.

See [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) answer.

Comment: It's clear that the OP knows how the `target` attibute works. *"If you want the user to fill in the form in a new window, you'll have to do a separated html page with that form and possible reuse it."* No, they don't.